# Run model from script

Tags: arcpy, layers, fields-attributes

This is my script where I am trying to use `selectby_attribute`
within a model, based on a field, F*.  There are 6 fields, so I want 6 derived layers.  Then I am going to use bearing and distance tool on each of these output layers.  I cannot pass query to the model.  How do I call a script from my 1st model, then call a model from this script?

```
import arcpy, sys, string, os

#arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#FList = arcpy.GetparameterAsText(1)
#F_list = FList.split(";")
#arcpy.ListFields(in_FC, "Rev_2016_F*")

#arcpy.AddMessage(tableName)
arcpy.AddMessage("The table %s exists" % (in_FC))
CurrentWorkspace = r"D:\Fort_Belvoir\Conservation\Conservation.gdb"

#in_Table = "D:\Fort_Belvoir\Conservation\Conservation.gdb\QryTab4_CopyRows"

#tbx = arcpy.AddToolbox("C:/Temp/MyToolbox.tbx")
tbx = arcpy.AddToolbox(r"D:\Fort_Belvoir\Conservation\PIF.tbx")
#arcpy.AddMessage("this is toolbox %s" % (tbx))

# Get a list of field objects
#
num = 0
fields = arcpy.ListFields(in_FC, "Rev_2016_F*", "LONG")

for field in fields:

    # Check the field name, perform a calculation when finding the field 'Flag'
    #
    # Local variables
    anum = str(num)
    thetab = "F" + anum
    arcpy.AddMessage(thetab)
    #arcpy.SetParameter(1, SR)
    theFld = field.name
    arcpy.AddMessage(field.name)
    arcpy.AddMessage(theFld)
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(num))
    anum = str(num)
    arcpy.AddMessage(anum)
    thetab = "F" + anum
    arcpy.AddMessage(thetab)

    out_FC = r"D:\Fort_Belvoir\Conservation\Conservation.gdb\PIF" + os.sep + thetab

    try:
        arcpy.AddMessage(out_FC)
        arcpy.SetParameter(1, theFld)
        arcpy.SetParameter(2, out_FC)
        tbx.Model2_Toolbox(theFld, out_FC)


    except:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Failed")

    arcpy.AddMessage(out_FC)
    num = num + 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [@PolyGeo told](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304635/run-model-from-script#comment491341_304635):

> I suggest you look at ImportToolbox rather than AddToolbox. However, I
>   suspect using a single Python Script tool may be simpler than mixing
>   ArcPy and ModelBuilder any more than necessary.

I think it is better not to mix models with arcpy scripts, however I also used to do it.
Assuming you have a local toolbox with models and scripts inside.
First step is to import toolbox.

`arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbox_path)`

And then everything inside toolbox become callable with arcpy. I.e. if you had a model called 'Calculate_distances' with input parameters 'feature_path' and 'out_path' you can type then:

`arcpy.Calculate_distances(r'path_to_fc', r'path_out')`

Be patient to call the the exactly model/script name, not its alias which is in toolbox.